# Alternate way of fuzzy pattern matching

Tags: python, nlp, pattern-matching

I am using fuzzy pattern matching on a large dataset and its time complexity is O(n). I want to reduce execution time.

**Is there any alternate way to do this?**

Here is my code

```
for k in range(len(patterns)):
    #patterns is list converted from dataframe of the dataset
    res = int(fuzz.partial_ratio(word,patterns[k]))
    rank[k]= res
    per.insert(k,res)
```

Comment: If you're processing the entire text, how do you expect to get a lesser complexity than O(N)?

Comment: Yes that's why I was asking for any alternate way to do that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can make a cutoff and match among the top 10 instead of the entire dataset

Here is the function

[Fuzzy Wuzzy String Matching on 2 Large Data Sets Based on a Condition - python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42847396/fuzzy-wuzzy-string-matching-on-2-large-data-sets-based-on-a-condition-python)